# Looking for an algorithm to solve a nonlinear optimization

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am looking for a general algorithm to find a global optimum solution of the following problem.
\begin{align*}
\min \quad & \sum_{a \in A} log(U_a(t_a(x_a)))\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad &  x_a=\sum_{r}\sum_{s}\sum_{k} f_{k}^{rs}\delta_{a,k}^{r,s} \quad \forall a\in A\\
\quad &\sum_{k}f_{k}^{rs}=d_{rs} \qquad~~~  \forall r,s\in Z\\
\quad & f_{k}^{rs} \geq0\qquad~~~~\quad \forall r,s\in Z,k\in \Pi_{rs} \\
\end{align*}
As a simple example, I would like to find the answer of vector $x$ for the following optimization problem.
\begin{align*}
\min \quad & \sum log(x_1(10+3x_1))+log(x_2(10+3x_2))\\
\textrm{s.t.} \quad &  x_1+x_2=12\\
\quad & 0\leq x_1,x_2\leq12\\
\end{align*}
Of course, there are some packages (in Python or R or Matlab) that will give the result. However, they usually give the local optimum points, and if you change the initial values, the answer is going to change. For this particular example, if we use the library(nloptr) in R, with the initial values $x_0=(10,2)$ the optimum point is (6.51,5.49) and with $x_0=(5,7)$ we get (6.45,5.55). But I applied the Lagrange method and solved it manually and I found $x_1 \approx 6.46 $. I'd appreciate any help to introduce me to any algorithm that I can apply to solve my problem.

Comment: The example problem you gave is unbounded, i.e., has a globally  optimal objective value of $-\infty$, which is achieved with one of the variables at 0 and the other at 12. DO you really mean to minimize, or do you want to maximize?

Comment: Thank you Mark. You are right. we need to find the global max point then. Do you know any algorithm to suggest? Thanks again

Comment: Use a numerical global optimization solver, such as BARON. That is free for small enough problems.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I'll try and wee how it goes